# Move a GameObject to the previous position of other GameObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to achieve something similar to the classic snake game, but, the player only moves one unit every time a button is pressed and the "tail (blue square)" needs to move to the previous position of the head

[image]

I want the blue square to always stay at the last position of the white square, not on top of it.

Here is my code:

```
[SerializeField] Transform segmentPrefab;

Vector2 moveInput;
Vector2 currentHeadPos;

//I want to add more segments to the tail so I created a list
List<Transform> segmentList;

void Start()
{
    //I add the head as the first object of the list
    segmentList = new List<Transform>();
    segmentList.Add(transform);
}

void OnMove(InputValue input)
{
    //I tried/expected to save the head Pos here and use it to move the segment with this
    currentHeadPos = transform.position;

    moveInput = input.Get<Vector2>();


    //Horizontal movement
    if (moveInput.x != 0)
    {
        transform.position = new Vector2(transform.position.x + moveInput.x, transform.position.y);
    }

    //Vertical movement
    if (moveInput.y != 0)
    {
        transform.position = new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y + moveInput.y);
    }

    //I loop through the list and move the last item to the position in front of it
    for (int i = segmentList[segmentList.Count - 1; i > 0, i --]
    {
      segmentList[i].position = segmentList[i - 1].position;
    }

   
}


//This works fine, is to add new objects to the list
void Connect()
{
    Vector3 offset = new Vector3(-1, 0f, 0f);
    Transform newSegment = Instantiate(segmentPrefab);
    newSegment.position = segmentList[segmentList.Count - 1].position + offset;
    segmentList.Add(newSegment);
}

private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision.CompareTag("Conector"))
    {
        Connect();
    }
}
```

I am fairly new to unity and coding and I can't figure out how to avoid the blue square ending on top of the one everytime it moves

Comment: Move your segment update loop before your Horizontal and Vertical movements. Your blue square is updating its position after you've moved your "head" segment (which I assume is at segmentList[0].

Comment: This is not about [tag:unityscript]

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that the segment at segmentList[0] is your white square, and all segments further down the list are your blue squares.

The following lines of code are moving your transform found at segmentList[0]:

```
    //Horizontal movement
    if (moveInput.x != 0)
    {
        transform.position = new Vector2(transform.position.x + moveInput.x, transform.position.y);
    }

    //Vertical movement
    if (moveInput.y != 0)
    {
        transform.position = new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y + moveInput.y);
    }
```

If your transform at segmentList[0] has already moved, then when you update `segmentList[1] = segmentList[0].position`, you have already updated segmentList[0] so it is actually the current position.

If you move the following code to earlier in your `OnMove` method, you should get your expected results:

```
    //I loop through the list and move the last item to the position in front of it
    for (int i = segmentList[segmentList.Count - 1; i > 0, i --]
    {
      segmentList[i].position = segmentList[i - 1].position;
    }
```